# Validation in rails one from two values must !=nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have to set validation in RoR model, to pass only, when one from first_name and last_name is not empty. It's passing first two tests

```
context "Validators:" do
  it "does not allow a User without a username" do
    expect(User.new(:username=> "")).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "does not allow a Profile with a null first and last name" do
    expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

But next test gets an error message

```
 1) Assignment rq11 Validators: allows a Profile with a null first name when last name present
 Failure/Error: expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>"Smith", :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
   expected `#<Profile id: nil, gender: "male", birth_year: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: "Smith", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>.valid?` to return true, got false
 # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:290:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Spec**

```
it "allows a Profile with a null first name when last name present" do
  expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>"Smith", :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
end
```

**Model**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :gender, inclusion: {in: %w(male, female), message: "Must be male or female"}
  validate :first_or_last_name



  def first_or_last_name
    if first_name  && last_name == nil
      errors.add(:first_name, "Cannot be both nil")
    end
  end

end
```

Is it problem with logic operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write the validation like this:

```
def first_or_last_name
  if first_name.blank? && last_name.blank?
    errors.add(:first_name, "cannot be both blank")
  end
end
```

Furthermore, you have a typo in definition of the `gender` validator. Remove the comma from `%w(male, female)`. The `%w` syntax generates an array of strings and doesn't need commas. At the moment it allows only `"male,"` and `"female"`.  Change it to:

```
validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(male female), 
                                message: "Must be male or female"}
```

Comment: Still the same error. There must be problem somewhere else

Comment: Are you on Rails 5? `belongs_to :user` in Rails 5 implies that the user must exist ([Read more about it](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html)).

Comment: No it's Rails 4. But thanks for advice. I solved the problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your code checks if first_name is defined and last_name is nil.

```
if first_name && last_name == nil
```

is equivalent to

```
if first_name && (last_name == nil)
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html. == comes before &&

You could try :

```
if (first_name || last_name) == nil
```

or

```
if first_name.nil? and last name.nil?
```

or

```
unless first_name or last_name
```

Finally, you probably don't want both names to be defined but empty, so :

```
if first_name.blank? and last_name.blank?
```

Comment: Checked all above. Still the same error. There must be problem somewhere else

Comment: If you comment out `validate :first_or_last_name`, does the spec pass?

Comment: Still not, but that guided me to the solution. The gender validator doesn't allow it to pass.

Answer (score 2):

The below validator was the problem.

```
validates :gender, inclusion: {in: %w(male, female), message: "Must be male or female"}
```

Comment: That line looks exactly like in your question. Remove the comma from `%w(male, female)`. It must look like this: `%w(male female)` Other wise you allow only `"male,"` and `"female"`